# Webpage made in 1024px width showing horizontal scrollbar only on 1024px screens

Tags: html

Webpage made in `1024px` width, but have a horizontal scrollbar in `1024` screens only.
Please help me to fix this issue using `jQuery` plugin or any other idea without reducing the width of whole site.

Comment: ...What? Make a much stronger effort in your English--I understand it may not be your first language but it is very hard to identify what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Adding code to your question is always helpful...

Answer (score 3):

Bec. actual width of `1024px` screen is about **`960px`** (`980px` max) taking in account vertical scrollbar and borders.

**UPDATE:** Possible solution is to wrap all site in the block and set `CSS` property `overflow-x: hidden;`. 
Everything what will overflow in horizontal will be omited while `Y` - vertical, will be of normal behavior.

Comment: Horizontal bar is showing only in 1024screens, have any idea to fit  such screens without reducing the width of whole website.

Comment: @SyamAmbu, Possible solution is to wrap it in a block and set style `overflow: hidden;`, but the rest of the page (*which is beyond the visible area*) will not be rendered and accessible.

Comment: @SyamAmbu, sorry, missed one thing `overflow-x: hidden;`. Everything what will overflow in horizontal will be omited. `Y` - vertical, will be of normal behavior.